# Regex : Match 1 to 60 or all

Tags: php, regex, string

I need some help on a REGEX in php (Symfony).

I want to match values 1 to 60 or string all.

For number I've use this : `^([1-5]?[0-9]|60)` but It match **0** ... And I don't now how can match "all".

Can you help me ?
Many thanks before

Comment: I feel that numeric range checks shouldn’t be in a regex.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to divide it into possibilities as follows:

```
^([1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|60|all)$
```

This gives you four possibilities:

- `[1-9]` the single-digit values.
- `[1-5][0-9]`: everything from ten to fifty-nine.
- `60`: sixty.
- `all`: your "all" option.

But keep in mind that regular expressions are not always the answer to *every* question.

Sometimes they're less useful for complicated value checks (though, in this case, it's a fairly simple one). Something like the following (pseudo-code):

```
def isAllOrOneThruSixty(str):
    if str == "all":
        return OK
    if str.matches ("[0-9]+"):
        val = str.convertToInt()
        if val >= 1 and val <= 60:
            return OK
    return BAD
```

can sometimes be, while more verbose, also more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

This will match all you need

```
^([1-9]|[1-5]\d|60|all)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making the `[1-5]` optional; turn it around, like so: `[1-5][0-9]?`.  Also you need to cover the single-digit `[6-9]`.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: You might have read an earlier version but I definitely edited that in before you gave me a down vote.  Your arguing is no longer correct; could you please remove the down vote?  Thanks.

Comment: I would, if I could, although I don't agree with your answer. However, too much time has already passed since the downvote. BTW: Obviously, you didn't edit your question before my downvote. See the upvote on my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are missing some parenthesis and you should switch the 60 and the rest, because otherwise it will only match the 6 in 60:

```
^((60|([1-5]?[0-9]))|all)
```